# ASP.NET MVC - Save file in the Network Attached Storage (NAS) that is located in the local network

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I will need to change the location where the files are being saved. They were being saved directly to the application, but I will switch to a path on the company network.

While making the change, I get an error that a part of the path cannot be found.

How do I make this change?

My Code:

```
//file Path's at WebConfig
<add key="TempUploadFolder" value="~\\naswebwin\web$\WEB_DESV\Apps-C\Farm-APL85\RDVE_RVEWEB" />
<add key="FinalUploadFolder" value="~\\naswebwin\web$\WEB_DESV\Apps-C\Farm-APL85\RDVE_RVEWEB\Apontamento" />


if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.FilePath))
     {
       //convert to list
       var fileList = model.FilePath.Split(';').Distinct().ToList();

       //for each file in the list, move from temporary folder to final folder
       model.FilePath = string.Join(";", fileList);

       string rootPath = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FinalUploadFolder"));
      _rootPathTempUpload = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TempUploadFolder"));

      var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_rootPathTempUpload, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .Where(s => fileList.Any(file => s.Contains(file)))
       .ToList();

         files.ForEach(fileToMove =>
         {
             var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToMove);
             System.IO.File.Move(fileToMove, System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName));
          });

       }
```

Comment: Using a Windows Explorer can you use same path to open the file?  The dollar sign indicates admin privilege so is the c# application running as an admin?  You can create a shortcut to VS and then right click the shortcut and select run as admin to get VS to run as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ~ sign from your uploading path like

```
<add key="TempUploadFolder" value="\\naswebwin\web$\WEB_DESV\Apps-C\Farm- 
 APL85\RDVE_RVEWEB\" />
```